# Getting Bing imagery to fully load in QGIS?

Tags: imagery, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I'm using QGIS 2.8 and by using the OpenLayers plugin, I can access Bing aerial imagery.  When I try to load it about half the tiles are missing.

How can I get it to fully load so that my map is completely covered by the imagery?

Comment: It seems like it might be a bug in OpenLayers, I've found that sometimes if I just panned back and forth it causes it to refresh with all of the tiles showing. This isn't really a fix, but it works for me most of the time.

Answer (score 3):

Try another plugin to add Bing Aerial basemaps in QGIS - QuickMapServices:

[image]

https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/quick_map_services/